# How to make two queries occur together in firestore rules

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a sensitive field 'goldCoins' in application, **''goldCoins' increments when a user answers a question correctly and should only increment once per question**. Field 'goldCoins' is in collection 'scorecard', whereas all correctly answered questions are stored in document *'userid/quizcode/questionNumber'*.

Now to update 'goldCoins' once I need a check to document 'questionNumber' Which are two queries, but this is a security lapse since anyone can easily bypass checking 'questionNumber' and increment value.

Here is my structure for scorecard:
[image]

Here is document questionNumber:
[image]

Here is code where increment of 'goldCoins' is done:

```
public boolean onEnter(String answer, Boolean onTime) {

  if (answer.equals(getValue().getAnswer())) {

    userScorecard.update("score", FieldValue.increment(getValue().getDifficulty()));
    userMetaScorecard.collection(quizName).document(String.valueOf(getValue().getQuestionNumber())).get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot ->{
      if (documentSnapshot.exists());
      else {
        userScorecard.update("goldCoins", FieldValue.increment(1));

        QuestionSolved qs = new QuestionSolved(onTime, FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
        userMetaScorecard.collection(quizName).document(String.valueOf(getValue().getQuestionNumber())).set(qs);
      }
    });
```

You can easily see that nested increment of 'goldCoins' can be bypassed by taking it out of the loop.

The only check I can think of is to check that 'goldCoins' are incremented by the value of 1 only. The rule is :

```
function shouldUpdateGold(){
   return request.resource.data.goldCoins <= resource.data.goldCoins+1 ||
   !request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['goldCoins'])
   }

match /scorecard/{userId}{
  allow get: if isSignedIn(); 
  allow list: if isSignedin() && request.query.limit<=3;
  allow create : if isSignedIn() && isUser(request.resource.id);
  allow update : if isSignedIn() && shouldUpdateGold()
  }
```

Now How should I check to update 'goldCoins' once per question, any architectural changes would be welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

Writing critical data from the client side is bad news.  I'd recommend one of two solutions, both involving a Cloud Function:

1. **REST API** - Remove write access to your RTDB and then set up a REST API on Cloud Functions/Run that sets the data thus preventing users from arbitrarily altering database values.
2. **RTDB Trigger** - Create a Cloud Function that subscribes to `onUpdate()` so that when a question is answered correctly the function will update the user's goldCoin total.  Client-side write access to `/scorecard/{id}/goldCoins` should be disabled.

Comment: I am on a spark plan, so couldn't write a function, suggest some architectural changes, if any.

Comment: There's no rule combination that you could use to prevent any half interested person from incrementing their gold count up to a million.  The Blaze plan includes the free tier from the Spark plan meaning it's possible you won't spend anything anyways.